# Using dotplots for splitting groups into a specific plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

A part of my data are:

```html
df1 <- read.table(text = " Temp State
88.28308628 Night
73.85659803 Day
66.92036484 Day
61.45664155 Day
62.11708502 Night
77.910035 Day
83.83020645 Night
52.95052026 Day
44.49119206 Day
72.39341998 Day
62.27060404 Night
67.24279876 Day
68.84254788 Night
59.08126966 Day
68.67741213 Day
69.21098024 Day
76.50589065 Night
58.09705376 Night
53.75199557 Day
48.68686495 Day
55.71440643 Day
55.15418576 Night
63.33067533 Night
77.10727238 Night
51.97454599 Night
76.07621845 Night
58.87549881 Night
50.8129286 Night
72.57671182 Day
51.05663584 Night
67.1617799 Day
70.91846403 Day
74.22424995 Day
47.83871548 Night
78.78818864 Night
52.65212397 Night
71.0489299 Day
62.24695615 Day
65.54017198 Day
69.71199466 Day
70.87168692 Day
61.48890886 Day
60.66793664 Day
84.53374499 Day
42.56109229 Day
57.85967169 Day
59.73001582 Day
60.47199271 Day
45.74175814 Day
53.98615543 Day
64.53890832 Day
64.45863708 Day
67.51300139 Day
40.68780829 Night
43.1833867 Night
50.31835652 Night
42.00035877 Night
65.33448204 Night
68.76201247 Night
56.60878371 Night
61.00470443 Night
57.98011171 Night
69.68496511 Night
65.4149201 Night
50.53736413 Night
57.43837368 Night
66.06097033 Night
65.35628006 Night
54.56469215 Night
71.37950699 Night
65.60217118 Night
62.05315748 Night

", header = TRUE)
```

I was searching in Google, but i could not find any solution and it is possible that I have missed something. I wonder if we could do it in ggplot2 or other packages. 
I want to get a plot to show groups as follows.

The x-axis represents Temps, which I was unable to show them.

[image: plot]

Is it possible to plot it in R?

Comment: How does your code to plot the data looks like?

Comment: https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/graphs/dotplot/create-the-graph/multiple-y-variables-simple/

Comment: Can the plot be in two separate facets, like with `facet_wrap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of plotting that graph with package `ggplot2`. It has a `geom_dotplot` that doesn't separate the plots by group but this can be done with `facet_wrap`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Temp, fill = State, colour = State)) +
  geom_dotplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~ State, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

## Edit.

A base R to plot dotplots is function `stripchart`. But this functions does not bin the data, they must be binned manually.

```
dftmp <- sapply(split(df1$Temp, df1$State), function(x){
  brks <- seq(floor(min(x)), ceiling(max(x)), length.out = length(x))
  i <- findInterval(x, c(brks, Inf))
  x[i]
})
dftmp <- unlist(dftmp)
dftmp <- data.frame(Temp = dftmp, State = names(dftmp))
dftmp$State <- sub("\\d+$", "", dftmp$State)
dftmp$State <- factor(dftmp$State, levels = c("Night", "Day"))

stripchart(Temp ~ State, data = dftmp, method = "stack", 
           ylim = c(0.8, 3), col = c("black", "red"), pch = 16)
abline(h = c(0.9, 1.9))

rm(dftmp)
```

[image]

Comment: @use2020 See the edit and my comment to the question, please.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, but it does not encourage me I want to get it as I have shown.

Comment: It seems that ggplot2 has some limitations for producing such plots?

Comment: @use2020 Yes, it does seem so. If the two groups are plotted without faceting they will both be put at the bottom.

Comment: Can we do it with other packages?

Comment: @use2020 Yes, it is possible. I had completely forgotten about base function `stripchart`, maybe because its name doesn't seem to relate to dot plots.